# How can I interface bare glass LCD to an arduino?

Tags: arduino, lcd

I am looking to interface a Casio 991es calculator's LCD to arduino. The LCD is just two bare glass plates glued together with lot of pins. I dont find any driver chip with it. How can I interface this LCD to arduino?

Edit: I think it is a dynamic LCD. This site has some info: http://dataweek.co.za/article.aspx?pklArticleId=2382&pklCategoryId=31
I dont understand the waveforms they provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I disassembled my Casio FX-85GT, I found that there were two main chips (both under epoxy blobs): what looked like a microcontroller, and a display controller. The display controller would drive the LCD directly. Unfortunately, driving a 128x64 pixel display without a dedicated driver will be next to impossible. A cheap solution is buying a ready-made display with a controller, e.g. [this one from SeeedStudio](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/serial-graphic-lcd-12864-st756567-ctrl-black-and-white-p-287.html?cPath=163_164).

I don't know about the 991es, but if it is just a character display you are after, [they are even cheaper](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/lcd-162-characters-green-yellow-back-light-p-62.html?cPath=163_164).

Comment: I had an idea of reusing the calculator for another purpose. I dont find any chip in its board. All it got is a chip on board covered with a black wax or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to interface any screen to an Arduino or other Microcontroller, you should make sure that the screen you intend to use has code libraries (in C, C++, Assembly, etc) for proper communication or else you will have a very difficult time with that screen. I would suggest you go on sparkfun and find an LCD screen + MC combo that have been tested to work nicely..